# How prove this $e=\frac{2}{1}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{6\cdot 8}{5\cdot 7}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdots$

Tags: calculus

I  see this nice equation:
$$e=\dfrac{2}{1}\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\dfrac{6\cdot 8}{5\cdot 7}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\dfrac{10\cdot 12\cdot 14\cdot 16}{9\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 15}\right)^{\frac{1}{8}}\cdots$$
and this equation who first found it? and   How prove it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Often"? Really?

Comment: Yes, I often  only see this equation introduce
some  china books.But I can't see this prove , Thank you,

Comment: My heart bleeds for the readers of those chinese books, both for being presented with the above equality and for it not being proved to them...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1005/1005.2712.pdf) (PDF) has the proof of your equation.

New Wallis- and Catalan-Type Infinite Products for $\pi,e$, and $\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}$

by Jonathan Sondow and Huang Yi

Comment: I couldn't find the proof in it, can you say on what page it is?

Comment: The formula in the problem statement is Catalan's formula, it is different from what the paper tries to prove.

Comment: Our equation is $(4)$. And we can find $(4)=(15)\times (20)^2$ and $(4)=(5)\times (20)$ on page $3$. You can find the other relations.